# Unit Testing with Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular7

I am trying to write unit test for this angular script:

```
export class DataService {
  private csrfToken: string = '';

  private isContentShow: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.token = this.cookieService.get('token');
  }

  public createData(data: Data) {
    try {
       this.http.post(  url,
                        data,
                        {
                          headers: new HttpHeaders({
                              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
                              'Authorization': this.token
                          })
                        })
      .subscribe(
        data => {
                this.isContentShow.next(true);
                },
        err => {
        this.showError();
        },
        () => console.log('Request Complete')
      );
      return true;
    } catch {
      this.showError();
      }
    }

  public getIsContentShow(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isContentShow.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

The test that I had so far and its running as expected.

```
 it('#getIsContentShow should return value from observable',
    (done: DoneFn) => {
    service.getIsContentShow().subscribe(value => {
      expect(value).toBe(true);
      done();
    });
  });
```

However I am trying to write the test for `createData()` function

I am able to mock the `HttpClient` using `HttpClientTestingModule` however I don't know how to handdle the `CookieService` and token ?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to set up your mock before creating the service for testing since you have the call to cookieService.get() inside your constructor.  Then when the service creates it will hit the mock and return the value you have set up to set `token`.

Comment: @dmcgrandle Do you think should i move the this.token inside the instructor to createData() funciton ? Not sure which way is better. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the requirements of your application, so I can't answer which way is "better".  It may make testing more straightforward.  If you are open to code re-write suggestions then I'd suggest doing a subscribe within a service is not a best practice - try and push that out to the component or better yet to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spies to spy on the cookieService get method. This way, you can write your unit test to test the combinations of returns you say the cookieService can provide.

[This link](https://www.saninnsalas.com/spyon-service-method-called-in-the-constructor/) says that you can spy on the prototype of the method in order to handle it how you like in the constructor.

```
it(
  "should call #getGeneralStats in the constructor",
  inject(
    [CookieService, HttpClient],
    (cookieService: CookieService, http: HttpClient) => {
      let mySpy = spyOn(cookieService, 'get').and.returnValue(<your value>);

      dataService = new DataService(http, cookieService);

      expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
  )
);
```

For you, this may depend on how you're writing your tests. The example shows the service being instantiated like `new ServiceName`, but it's also possible to use dependency injection to get the service. If you're using DI for the service you are testing, I'd have to research more how to do this (others please feel free to add your answer if you know how to do that)!